# How can I use filter() to find multiple items from a list of Ids?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm attempting fetch multiple items by an `id` property based on a list of `id`s.  To give an example lets use the function below.

```
findItems(idList: string[]){
    let fetchedItems: SomeType[] = [];

    idList.forEach(a=>{
        fetchedItems.push(DATASOURCE.find(b=> b.id === a));
    }

    return fetchedItems;
}
```

As you can see this function takes a list of `string`s and uses a `forEach()` method to individually find each item and push it to the `fetchedItems` array, which means if there's 10 items in that list there will be 10 consecutive calls to the same database.

Looking further into this curiosity it hit me that `filter()` is designed to do this exact thing.  I looked at the documentation on MDN and googled around a bit but I guess I don't know what to specifically search for to get the results I need to study into.  Can anyone show me how this can be done?

Answer (score 5):

Make `idList` into a `Set` (for less computational complexity), and then you can `.filter` on `DATASOURCE` by whether the `id` is included in the set:

```
findItems(idList: string[]){
    const ids = new Set(idList);
    return DATASOURCE.filter(({ id }) => ids.has(id));
}
```

This assumes that you don't have multiple items in `DATASOURCE` with duplicate IDs.

`Set.has` has `O(1)` complexity, whereas array methods like `.find` (or `.includes`, etc) have `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
findItems(idList: string[]){
    return DATASOURCE.filter(data => idList.includes(data.id));
}
```